# Adding an image in a text that is using column

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for couple of hours already why I can't get my picture going in my text. I use columns to aligne my text.

Picture of what I wouldlike to get

[image]

[Here's what I'm constantly getting - Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n7Lk3n3/4/)

```css
#text-columns {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
  -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
  -webkit-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
}

#fake_image {
  background-color: black;
  width: 67%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div id="fake_image"></div>

  <p id="text-columns">
    <strong>Ihiliquatior am quia numquam ipit, quis as pro culpa nus ma doluptatem rerum veria nosae nulligendit laccatate nus dit et, cullis sum dolupta comnis apitibusam ium dem volorum repreptatque es dellique sum nat.</strong>
    <br />
    <br /> In re que occum eum fugitatquati cori bea ni sequaes cum quatis del iunt fugit, omnitatus eiciis im arupid esectem vit, et repudam alitio. Ducia doluptatibus impedi deliatur res sequiam conseresto omniatiunda sit aut aligend undunt am incit aut lab
    ipsuntius solore, nonectorerum quid ut repella experum que quam quam iminiscium, que inus quo in ese cum es volupti isciendit, quate consequamus et del iur, aut acersperiat utempor adis modio. Aquidem poriam, sum cullant ioribus volupit ullorianda
    cum nimendist dolumqui ommolupta nus maxim estiscipsunt hari ut hil molor ariost ut ipsam sam explibus estio volorer eicabor erferum eatem aut int fugiae nimus invel etur alita illoren imporiam cum quibus is et quas et que pra desequa speriati sitassitat.
    Tas desequi sapeles trumquis exceper erescilibus. Epernat assinih itatumque aliquis soluptam, volut quas nonsequias quamust reneces totatur rescidem. Viducia venimag niatusandel ipiet volectota volorit lam as a autectibus eum rem into dolore, temperferum,
    sit re pero dolent intio. Equaecus dolest, secuptiur aut lanim vellectur sectia pratia pos none exeriosamus.
  </p>

</div>
```

I tried to search but it does not seem to have any page that exist related to this problem

Thanks for your time

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible. `:(`

Comment: Humm.... It may be possible! I would absolutly need it.

Comment: Im not sure how helpful this'll be but check this out. https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/ This uses images and the method you're using. So you may find something useful?

Comment: Thx but unfortunatly, the link is for image-only or texte-only and they do not explain anything about the two in the same div.

Comment: Why another div instead of an image though? I found something called `column-span` so you can span over 2 columns but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Does it have to use columns?

Comment: Yes it must have to use three columns and I added a div instead of an img because I didn't have a link to the picture. However with div, it's the same problem I guess.

Comment: well I cheated by doing this but as soon as I resize it it moves about and I've had to use two images https://jsfiddle.net/3n7Lk3n3/5/ :/ Maybe you could use a positioning method? Do you know if you can use column padding or something like that? So use padding-top on the right two columns and position the image absolute in the parent to be in that location?

Comment: Actually, that is not really ok. I've got a screen with 2540x1440 or smth like that and we can clearly see that there is two black rectangle and one is not in a good place but that would've been a good idea.

Comment: No, there is no property that will allow you to span CSS columns *unless* you want to span them **all** - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/column-span/

Comment: Yea sorry, I've found this? This guy manages to do it with a header? http://jsfiddle.net/uC72x/53/ But I can't seem to replicate this with an image :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** image has a **known size and will always be standing first and floatting right**, then a negative margin of height of image on **`:first-child`** should do:

```css
div {
  background:#FEDD31;/* demo extra */
  padding:0.5em 0.5%;/* demo extra */
  text-shadow:0 0 white/* demo extra */
}
#text-columns {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
  -moz-column-rule-width: 2px;
  -webkit-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  color:#0675B4;/* demo extra */
  text-shadow:1px 1px white/* demo extra */
}

#text-columns strong:first-child {
  margin:calc(-100px  - 1em) 0  -1em; /* unless margins on p are reset, then no need of calc() */
  display:block;
  color:purple;/* demo extra */
}
#fake_image {
  background-color: black;
  width: 66%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 3px white, inset 1px 1px 1px  white, inset 0 0  1px 10px #333/* demo extra */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="fake_image"></div>

  <p id="text-columns">
    <strong>Ihiliquatior am quia numquam ipit, quis as pro culpa nus ma doluptatem rerum veria nosae nulligendit laccatate nus dit et, cullis sum dolupta comnis apitibusam ium dem volorum repreptatque es dellique sum nat.</strong>
    <br />
    <br /> In re que occum eum fugitatquati cori bea ni sequaes cum quatis del iunt fugit, omnitatus eiciis im arupid esectem vit, et repudam alitio. Ducia doluptatibus impedi deliatur res sequiam conseresto omniatiunda sit aut aligend undunt am incit aut lab
    ipsuntius solore, nonectorerum quid ut repella experum que quam quam iminiscium, que inus quo in ese cum es volupti isciendit, quate consequamus et del iur, aut acersperiat utempor adis modio. Aquidem poriam, sum cullant ioribus volupit ullorianda
    cum nimendist dolumqui ommolupta nus maxim estiscipsunt hari ut hil molor ariost ut ipsam sam explibus estio volorer eicabor erferum eatem aut int fugiae nimus invel etur alita illoren imporiam cum quibus is et quas et que pra desequa speriati sitassitat.
    Tas desequi sapeles trumquis exceper erescilibus. Epernat assinih itatumque aliquis soluptam, volut quas nonsequias quamust reneces totatur rescidem. Viducia venimag niatusandel ipiet volectota volorit lam as a autectibus eum rem into dolore, temperferum,
    sit re pero dolent intio. Equaecus dolest, secuptiur aut lanim vellectur sectia pratia pos none exeriosamus.
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: OK...it didn't work when I posted the original comment.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Replacing the margin calc in % makes it responsive, then it's perfect! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Awesome! `:)` Still, this is a hack! `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using:

- absolute positioning for the image (rather than a float)
- top padding for `#text-columns`
- negative top margin and vertical alignment for `.standfirst`

```css
#container {
width: 100%;
}

#text-columns {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
  -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
  -webkit-column-rule-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
  -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: justify;
  padding-top:110px;
}

#text-columns .standfirst {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: -115px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
vertical-align:top;
font-weight:bold;
}

#fake_image {
  background-color: black;
  width: 67%;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  
<div id="fake_image"></div>
  
<p id="text-columns">

  <span class="standfirst">Ihiliquatior am quia numquam ipit, quis as pro culpa nus ma doluptatem rerum veria nosae nulligendit laccatate nus dit et, cullis sum dolupta comnis apitibusam ium dem volorum repreptatque es dellique sum nat.</span>

In re que occum eum fugitatquati cori bea ni sequaes cum quatis del iunt fugit, omnitatus eiciis im arupid esectem vit, et repudam alitio. Ducia doluptatibus impedi deliatur res sequiam conseresto omniatiunda sit aut aligend undunt am incit aut lab
    ipsuntius solore, nonectorerum quid ut repella experum que quam quam iminiscium, que inus quo in ese cum es volupti isciendit, quate consequamus et del iur, aut acersperiat utempor adis modio. Aquidem poriam, sum cullant ioribus volupit ullorianda
    cum nimendist dolumqui ommolupta nus maxim estiscipsunt hari ut hil molor ariost ut ipsam sam explibus estio volorer eicabor erferum eatem aut int fugiae nimus invel etur alita illoren imporiam cum quibus is et quas et que pra desequa speriati sitassitat.
    Tas desequi sapeles trumquis exceper erescilibus. Epernat assinih itatumque aliquis soluptam, volut quas nonsequias quamust reneces totatur rescidem. Viducia venimag niatusandel ipiet volectota volorit lam as a autectibus eum rem into dolore, temperferum,
    sit re pero dolent intio. Equaecus dolest, secuptiur aut lanim vellectur sectia pratia pos none exeriosamus.
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: The div keeps going either on the text or to far away from the text. However thanks.